# How can assign a default value for Html.EditorFor in js function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

This is my View..

```
<div style="float: left; width: 450px; text-align:left; margin-left:80px">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="label" style="float: left; width: 80px">Date From: </div>
                    <div class="control">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateFrom, new { ID = "datefrom" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateFrom, null, new { style = "color: red" })
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="label" style="float: left; width: 80px">Date To: </div>
                    <div class="control" >
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTo, new { ID = "dateto" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateTo, null, new { style = "color: red" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="relative" name="relative" onclick="validate()" />Is Relative</div>

            </div>
```

And this is my js function:

```
 function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById('relative').checked) {
            document.getElementById('@Html.IdFor(model => model.DateFrom)').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateFrom, new { @Value = DateTime.Now })');
            document.getElementById('@Html.IdFor(model => model.DateTo)').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTo, new { @Value = DateTime.Now })');
        } else {
            document.getElementById('@Html.IdFor(model => model.DateFrom)').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('@Html.IdFor(model => model.DateTo)').disabled = false;
        }
    }
```

How can assign a default value (DateTiem.Now) to Html.EditorFor? Thanks a lot for your Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

No Body has replied to this question in a long time. If somebody else trying to solve the similar issue.

try this in your Javascript.

```
document.getElementById('@Html.IdFor(model => model.Draw)')
```